# Getting 404.php instead of single-<post-type>.php

Tags: custom-post-types

Trying to get a post to show up at http://beernews.org/supporter/rare-beer-club/ but am getting 404 instead. An example of what the page should look like is: http://beernews.org/brewery/5-rabbit-brewery/. When I do a search, it shows up as an excerpt in the results. Just can't get the template single-supporter.php to trigger for some reason. I have set up the post type (And corresponding taxonomy) exactly like every other post type and taxonomy.

I have flushed the cache and CDN.

I don't have a live server testing environment for this but the same exact code works on localhost. Because it is live with heavy traffic, I am reluctant to turn on debugging features that would show on front end.

Register post type code in functions.php

```
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Supporters', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Supporter', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'supporter'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Supporter'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Supporter'),
    'new_item' => __('New Supporter'),
    'all_items' => __('All Supporters'),
    'view_item' => __('View Supporter'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Supporters'),
    'not_found' =>  __('No supporters found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No supporters found in Trash'), 
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => 'Supporters'

  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true, 
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'taxonomies' => array ('beer','category'),
    'supports' => array('title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','page-attributes','revisions','comments','post-formats')
  ); 
  register_post_type('supporter',$args);
```

Register taxonomy code in functions.php

```
   // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Supporters', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Supporter', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Supporters' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Supporters' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Supporter' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Supporter:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Supporter' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Supporter' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Supporter' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Supporter Name' )
  );

  register_taxonomy('supporter',array('beer','post'),
    array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'supporters-bp' )
  ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. For some reason, I had to go to my permalinks page and click 'Save Changes' for this to show up. It is bewildering.

Comment: I think that flushes the rewrite options in your htaccess. Every time that you add something like a new post type you have to do this or use `add_action('admin_init', 'flush_rewrite_rules');` in order to flush the cache rewrite rules. ( from http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries )

Comment: Important note, if adding to hook, that rules should be flushed **once** after changes.

Answer (score -3):

You need to flush the Permalinks on post save.

You can add this function to the functions.php file:

```
// ==============================================
// Flush Permalinks on Save Post
// ==============================================

//Create a Function to Flush Permalinks
function nr_flush_permalinks() {
    /* Call WordPress rewrite function to flush rules.
        http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/flush_rules */
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    // Do anything you wish to do more....
}
//Add Function "n_flush_permalinks()" to the "save_post" action hook:
add_action( 'save_post', 'nr_flush_permalinks()' );
```

Comment: On `save_post`? That’s not the proper action.

Comment: Quoting directly from the 2nd ¶ of the [`flush_rules()` Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/flush_rules): "**Because this function can be extremely costly in terms of performance, it should be used as sparingly as possible** - such as during activation or deactivation of plugins or themes. Every attempt should be made to avoid using it in hooks that execute on each page load, such as `init`." (emphasis mine)

Comment: Copied from @Rarst comment on previous answer. "Important note, if adding to hook, that rules should be flushed **once** after changes.